# Scene Builder with ArcGIS API

Tags: arcgis-runtime-sdk-java

How to use Scene Builder to create fxml UI in JAVA using ArcGIS API libraries?

After adding ArcGIS libs to Scene Builder i got only some AttributionControl picture. I dont have any Scenes or Maps. How can i add all arcgis elements to work with?

[image]

My fxml interface code(file "sample.fxml"):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <?import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane?>
   <?import com.esri.arcgisruntime.mapping.view.SceneView?>

   <StackPane fx:controller="sample.Controller" 
   xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/11.0.2" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml">
       <SceneView fx:id="sceneView"/>
   </StackPane>
```

My Controller code:

```
 package sample;
    
       import com.esri.arcgisruntime.layers.Layer;
       import com.esri.arcgisruntime.layers.RasterLayer;
       import com.esri.arcgisruntime.mapping.ArcGISScene;
       import com.esri.arcgisruntime.mapping.Basemap;
       import com.esri.arcgisruntime.mapping.BasemapStyle;
       import com.esri.arcgisruntime.mapping.Viewpoint;
       import com.esri.arcgisruntime.mapping.view.SceneView;
       import com.esri.arcgisruntime.raster.Raster;
       import java.net.URL;
       import java.util.ResourceBundle;
       import javafx.fxml.FXML;
       import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
       import javafx.scene.control.ListView;

   public class Controller implements Initializable {

       @FXML
       private SceneView sceneView;    
       private Basemap basemap;

       public Controller() {
       }

       @FXML
       public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle resourceBundle) {
           this.basemap = new Basemap();
           ArcGISScene scene = new ArcGISScene(this.basemap);
           this.sceneView.setArcGISScene(scene);
           Raster raster = new 
   Raster("C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\maps\\tif\\my_new_task.tif");
           RasterLayer rasterLayer = new RasterLayer(raster);
           scene.getOperationalLayers().add(rasterLayer);
           rasterLayer.addDoneLoadingListener(() -> {
               if (rasterLayer.getLoadStatus() == LoadStatus.LOADED) {
                   System.out.println("raster added");
                   Envelope extent = rasterLayer.getFullExtent();
                   Viewpoint viewpoint = new Viewpoint(extent);
                   this.sceneView.setViewpoint(viewpoint);
               } else {
                   System.out.println("Error");
               }

           });
       }
   }
```

My Main code:

```
 package sample;

   import com.esri.arcgisruntime.mapping.ArcGISScene;
   import com.esri.arcgisruntime.mapping.Basemap;
   import com.esri.arcgisruntime.mapping.view.SceneView;
   import javafx.application.Application;
   import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
   import javafx.scene.Parent;
   import javafx.scene.Scene;
   import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
   import javafx.stage.Stage;



   public class Main extends Application {

       @Override
       public void start(Stage Stage) throws Exception{

           FXMLLoader loader = new 
   FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("/sample/sample.fxml"));

           Parent root = loader.load();           
        
           Scene scene = new Scene(root);

           Stage.setTitle("MapArcgis");
           Stage.setWidth(800);
           Stage.setHeight(700);

           Stage.setScene(scene);
           Stage.show();
       }

       public static void main(String[] args) {
           Application.launch(args);
       }
   }
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with "SceneBuilder".  Can you provide a link to where some information about it can be found, please?

Comment: I mean Scene Builder app. thx

Comment: That's not helping me to find any documentation on it.  Can you give more information about precisely what you are using, please?

Comment: Are you using something from https://developers.arcgis.com/java/ ?

Comment: Scene Builder 16.0 https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/javafxscenebuilder-info.html. This program is used in javafx applications to create fxml interfaces by drag and drop and not by writing fxml file manually.

Comment: Yes, i use this instruction  https://developers.arcgis.com/java/install-and-set-up/

Comment: But i dont use "StackPane stackPane = new StackPane(); Scene scene = new Scene(stackPane);" i use fxml file with my UI definition instead of it("sample.fxml") and load it and add it to the scene                                                              
        FXMLLoader loader = new 
        FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("/sample/sample.fxml"));
        Parent root = loader.load();
        Scene scene = new Scene(root); It's like mvc JavaFX pattern

Comment: And i try to create this sample.fxml file using Scene Builder and not by writing all ArcGIS api elements mannualy in sample.fxml file

Answer (score 0):

1. Adding this lines
   com.esri.arcgisruntime.internal.mapping.view.AttributionControl
   com.esri.arcgisruntime.mapping.view.Callout
   com.esri.arcgisruntime.internal.mapping.view.CalloutDefaultView
   to the C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\Scene Builder\Library\filter.txt
2. Adding jniLibs folder(from downloaded folder arcgis runtimr sdk) to the folder C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\SceneBuilder

This 2 acts solved my problem